# In football (soccer), at what point(s) does the possession of a team start?

Tags: rules, football

For example, the defending team touches and stops the ball but suddenly, an attacking player gets the ball. Can we say defending team gained possession once?

Comment: You can say almost anything you like. Why is it important to you whether the defending team "gained possession" or not?

Comment: @PhilipKendall I am curious whether "attacking phase of play" is reset in such a scenario in a case of possible VAR check.

Comment: An attacking phase is not neccessarily restricted to a single possession. If the defense gained possession for a second and lost it again it would still be the same attacking phase.

Comment: @dly So, can we say at least 2-3 seconds must pass between the defender's stopping the ball and the attacker's retaking the ball in order attacking phase to restart?